# Обращение к функции в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть следующий код:

```py
def func():
   x= input()
   y=input()
   if (x!=y):
       return True
   else
        return False
```

Далее в главной программе мне нужно обратиться к данной функции. То есть, если `true`, то `print('nice')`, если `false`, то `print('bad')`.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы вызвать функцию используется нотация с круглыми скобками: `func()`.

***Пример:***

```py
def func():
    x = input()
    y = input()
    if x != y:
        return True
    else:
        return False


if func():
    print('nice')
else:
    print('bad')
```

*Примечания:*

- Вы пропустили `:` после `else`.
- У Вас разные отступы в блоках `def`, `if` и `else` (3, 4, 5). *Желательно 4 пробела.*
- Несоответствие `PEP-8` (не следует обрамлять условие в скобки без необходимости, а вот пробелы между оператором `=` были бы очень желанны)

**P. S.:**

Я бы сделал это немного иначе.
Для начала вынес бы `input()` за пределы функции а его результаты передал бы как аргументы при вызове.
Также упростил бы условие, возвращая сразу результат проверки, и использовал бы аналог тернарного оператора (но это не обязательно):

```py
def func(x, y):
    return x != y


a = input()  # Ещё можно так: "a, b = input(), input()"
b = input()  # Или так: "a, b = (input() for x in range(2))"

print('nice') if func(a, b) else print('bad')
```

Оптимизации можно продолжить.
Для начала - использовать аналог тернарного оператора на строки для печати.
А если отказаться от функции и переменных, то можно вообще сделать это в строчку:

```py
print('nice' if input() != input() else 'bad')
```